# I can't install python modules on Apple Silicon

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, homebrew, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon

I have macbook air m1 and I can't install python modules like numpy, matplotlib.
I install python3.8 with homebrew then install virtaulenv. In venv, when I run 'pip install numpy' the error shows up:
'...  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly'
I tried 'pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel' doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Install python 3.9.1 from python.org (ARM version)
Then, for Numpy:
python3 -m pip install cython
python3 -m pip install --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517 numpy==1.20rc1

Then, for matplotlib:
brew install libjpeg
python3 -m pip install matplotlib

This works for me on a Mac min with Apple Silicon.
No luck for SciPy yet, though.

Comment: Tried to install numpy as described above and getting an import error -- ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

Comment: When you check the architecture of the python process in Activity Monitor, is it Apple or Intel?

Comment: What about pandas? :)